# Why std::endl can't be used after std::cin

Tags: c++

What's the diff between \n and endl? Is \n faster?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() 
{
    cout << "Please enter 2 numbers:" << endl;
    int a = 0, b = 0;
    cin >> a >> b;
    cout << "The sum of " << a << " and " << b << " is " << a + b << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your title has nothing to do with the actual question.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, '\n' is faster here. `std::endl` will additionally call `flush()` which is not needed in this case.

Comment: In many implementations, writing `'\n' ` also flushes